# Copy flourish studio bar chart race names

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, copy-paste

I created a bar chart race for sample in flourish studio website that following is link of my chart:

https://public.flourish.studio/visualisation/15565937/

Now I want to copy all left side country names in a text file.
Note that some names appear during chart changes and I want to collect all names that available in this bar chart.

Do you have any idea to do this?
**note that I don't request free script or code, I need only idea and help to create my script. for example I want to know that what programming language can do this and how?**